# Access fields of fields using lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), suppose I have two classes.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Book {
    private String name;
    private BookDetail bookDetail;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BookDetail {
    private String description;
    private String author;
}
```

Now I can get the author of a book like this.

```
Book book = new Book("name1", new BookDetail("description1", "author1"));
System.out.println(book.getBookDetail().getAuthor());
```

This is a bit of redundant, is there any way to get the author directly, like this?

```
Book book = new Book("name1", new BookDetail("description1", "author1"));
System.out.println(book.getAuthor());
```

Comment: why just not to simply write it by hand? I mean create `getAuthor` method inside `Book` and call `BookDetail#getAuthor` from it.

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev Yes, I can do that manually, I'm just curious whether lombok has a better way to do it.

Comment: I've looked in their [features description](https://projectlombok.org/features/) and there is no such option to do it with pure Lombok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a bit of redundant, is there any way to get the author directly, like this?

No, there's definitely nothing like this in Lombok. What comes closest, is the `@Singular` Lombok `@Builder` [feature](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder), which is pretty [cool](https://projectlombok.org/features/Singular-snippet.html), but won't help you, as it's 1. for builder and 2. for collections only.

I'd consider flattening you structure. Using `BookDetail` make it way more complicated and I'd do it only if it offered me a big advantage elsewhere.

Note also that having a settable mutable field gives you two possibilities, how you can change the `description`: Either by `getBookDetail().setDescription(....)` or by `setBookDetail(....)`.

You may want to clone the `BookDetail` in the getter and setter (Lombok can't do it for you).

---

Another option is making `BookDetail` (`@Value` instead of `@Data`) and use `@Wither` instead of `@Setter`. This makes changing the `description` pretty inconvenient

```
getBookDetail(getBookDetail().withDescription(....));
```

but may be worth it, sometimes (in general, not for entities, so probably not in your case). I'd love if Lombok supported that, but it doesn't and probably never will (just like what you wanted, it requires access to another class, which is very problematic at the compile stage it runs in).